# Connecting with Java to Azure

Tags: java, android

I try to write a small Andoid app that stores Pictures/Videos in an Microsoft Windows Azure Blob container..

Simple Code from an example I found:

```
public class BlobTesting extends Fragment {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "BlobTesting";

public String azureStorageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=my-azure-blob-storage-name;AccountKey=my-azure-primary-access-key";

public BlobTesting() {
    try {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount azureAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(azureStorageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client.
       CloudBlobClient azureClient = azureAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and I always get an "exeption java.lang.verifyError in createCloudBlobClient() when debugging this app on my android phone.

Do you have any ideas ?

Would be really great...

Comment: I think a better solution is to create cloud service in azure. There-by from android you can use cloud service via http which would will upload the image to azure cloud storage

Comment: i'm going to try this .... But where is the advantage?

Comment: As android application resides with the user hence there can be security issue of breaking the app and getting the crendentials of ur azure storage. Also, if you making it as HTTP endpoint for uploading images to ur server then it can accessed via any other application (may be an ios app) you develop without much code.

Comment: okay... Thanks .... I'll try the Azure Rest API instead...